# How to resize my dual-boot partitions

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, partitioning

I have a dual-boot laptop with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Currently, the Windows side has too much disk space, and I want to resize things so that the Ubuntu side has more.

Firstly, I went into the Windows disk management and shrunk the Windows partition by 20GB. I then wanted to expand the Ubuntu partition, but it seemed like this option was greyed out.

Can I expand the Linux partition from Windows or do I need to be in Ubuntu or do I need to create a boot disk and do it that way?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Have you considered using tools like https://www.acronis.com/en-us/personal/disk-manager/

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't sure if I needed tools or if it could be done with existing system tools.